# Using stats_get_csv to return a list of popular posts by views with thumbnails

Tags: plugin-jetpack, csv, statistics

I recently learned that if you have WordPress.com Stats installed, you can take advantage of `stats_get_csv()` (Part of the [WordPress.com Stats Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/)).

```
<?php if ( function_exists('stats_get_csv') && $top_posts = stats_get_csv('postviews', 'days=-1&limit=4') ) : ?>
    <ol>
<?php foreach ( $top_posts as $p ) : ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $p['post_permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $p['post_title']; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's how I have my code set up now. The problem is that it shows pages as well as posts. Also, I want to add the featured thumbnail next to each item as well as an array of custom post types. Is this possible? If so, can someone help me out?

Comment: Please share of which software the function `stats_get_csv()` is part of. That will help others to answer your question.

Comment: @hakre I believe it's WP.com Stats - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/

Comment: Yes, it is the Wordpress.com Stats plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The API returns the following columns when you query the `postviews` table:

- date
- post_id
- post_title
- post_permalink
- views

For my blog the `post_id` column was either empty or `0` (for the homepage). So unless you have good values there, you will have to work from the `post_permalink` value and determine whether it is a page or a post (via a query on the database or a regex on the URL?), and then query your database for the post thumbnail, because the WordPress.com stats API does not collect info on that.

Answer (score 2):

The WordPress.com Stats API does not currently offer a post_type filter. You can implement one yourself in one of a number of ways. The basic idea is to loop over the `post_id`s to figure out which ones have a `post_type` of `post`. In your loop you can use something like this:

```
$post = get_post($p['post_id']);
if ( !isset($post->post_type) || $post->post_type != 'post' )
    continue;
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
else
    $thumbnail = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

As to the excluding pages, if you have only a few pages, you can do it [as described here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/stats-plugin-excluding-homepage-from-stats_get_csv-results#post-1771562):

Inside your foreach loop, before the <li> add:

```
 $postTitle = $single_post['post_title'];
    if($postTitle == 'Home page') {
```