# Wordpress.com Stats stats_get_csv with custom field?

Tags: csv

I am trying to figure out how to add a custom field to display an image instead of a title on the stats_get_csv from Wordpress stats.

```
  <?php if ( function_exists('stats_get_csv') && $top_posts = stats_get_csv('postviews', 'days=2&limit=6') ) : ?>
    <ol>
<?php foreach ( $top_posts as $p ) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $p['post_permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $p['post_title']; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Update**

```
<?php if ( function_exists('stats_get_csv') && $top_posts = stats_get_csv('postviews', 'days=2&limit=6') ) : ?>
    <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Image', true) ) : ?>
        <ol>
            <?php foreach ( $top_posts as $p ) : ?>
                <li>
                    <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Image', true) ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" height='100' width='100' />
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what does `stats_get_csv` look like?

Comment: What image do you want to display? There is [another question about displaying the post thumbnail](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12189/using-stats-get-csv-to-return-a-list-of-popular-posts-by-views-with-thumbnails).

Comment: I saw the post thumbnail question but I want to use it with a custom  field instead of a post thumbnail. Every post on the site has a custom field of 'Image' and I would like to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return of that function should have post ID, right? Then it's straight [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) using that ID and name of your field.

**Update**

In your second code snippet `$post` is global variable, `$post->ID` is not tied in any way with return of `stats_get_csv()` function. You need something like from first example (`$p['post_permalink']`), just figure out if there is a field with ID.

Also you don't need wrapping `if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Image', true) )` that would make sense only for single current post, not for loop of posts.

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried it via that page and it only shows the same image repeating 6 times. I have also tried http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values

Comment: @Spewf could you please add your code to the question? I am not sure I would be able to help since I don't use WP stats, but maybe someone else will be.

Comment: Do you not see the code at the top? I added it correctly. You can also see the code at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/faq/

Comment: @Spewf that code has nothing to do with my suggestion to try and access post meta via ID that should be (I think) returned with rest of stuff and what might fail when you try that

Comment: @Rarst. Sorry I didn't understand what you meant the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't seem to figure out a way of adding it to the code. I looked through the stats plugin file and looked on various sites to see if there was a way but I guess not.